Documents processed are 0 when Azure Search is indexing documents from Blob storage
I have followed this below [tutorial][1] till the end by making necessary changes like the API key and the ConnectionString to connect to my datasource, creating index and indexers. At the end of running the indexer, the number of documents processed is 0. I have 2 JSON files in the container that I am reading from. I am unsure why the document processed count shows as 0. I don't have any complex networking or security rules configured.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-semi-structured-data
POST {{baseUrl}}/indexers?api-version=2024-07-01  HTTP/1.1
  Content-Type: application/json
  api-key: {{apiKey}}

    {
      "name" : "ny-philharmonic-indexer",
      "dataSourceName" : "employerdata-container",
      "targetIndexName" : "ny-philharmonic-index",
      "parameters" : { 
        "configuration" : { 
          "parsingMode" : "jsonArray", "documentRoot": "/programs"}
        },
      "fieldMappings" : [ 
      ]
    }

POST {{baseUrl}}/indexes?api-version=2024-07-01  HTTP/1.1
  Content-Type: application/json
  api-key: {{apiKey}}

    {
      "name": "ny-philharmonic-index",  
      "fields": [
        {"name": "programID", "type": "Edm.String", "key": true, "searchable": true, "retrievable": true, "filterable": true, "facetable": true, "sortable": true},
        {"name": "orchestra", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "retrievable": true, "filterable": true, "facetable": true, "sortable": true},
        {"name": "season", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "retrievable": true, "filterable": true, "facetable": true, "sortable": true},
        { "name": "concerts", "type": "Collection(Edm.ComplexType)", 
          "fields": [
            { "name": "eventType", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "retrievable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": false, "facetable": false},
            { "name": "Location", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "retrievable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": false, "facetable": true },
            { "name": "Venue", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "retrievable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": false, "facetable": true },
            { "name": "Date", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": false, "retrievable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": false, "facetable": true },
            { "name": "Time", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": false, "retrievable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": false, "facetable": true }
          ]
        },
        { "name": "works", "type": "Collection(Edm.ComplexType)", 
          "fields": [
            { "name": "ID", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "retrievable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": false, "facetable": false},
            { "name": "composerName", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "retrievable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": false, "facetable": true },
            { "name": "workTitle", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "retrievable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": false, "facetable": true },
            { "name": "conductorName", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "retrievable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": false, "facetable": true },
            { "name": "soloists", "type": "Collection(Edm.String)", "searchable": true, "retrievable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": false, "facetable": true }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-semi-structured-data


do search in index. are you getting results or empty.

i got empty results

added solution below. check if it works @Prashant

Possible reason you are getting zero processed documents is the data in your json file.
In data source you given the documentRoot as /programs and your json data should look something like below.
{
  "programs": [
  {
  "id": "7358870b-65c8-43d5-ab56-514bde52db88-0.1",
  "programID": "11640",
  "orchestra": "New York Philharmonic",
  "season": "2011-12",
  "concerts": [
    {
      "eventType": "Non-Subscription",
      "Location": "Manhattan, NY",
      "Venue": "Avery Fisher Hall",
      "Date": "2011-09-07T04:00:00Z",
      "Time": "7:30PM"
    },
    {
      "eventType": "Non-Subscription",
      "Location": "Manhattan, NY",
      "Venue": "Avery Fisher Hall",
      "Date": "2011-09-08T04:00:00Z",
      "Time": "7:30PM"
    }
  ],
  "works": [
    {
      "ID": "5733*",
      "composerName": "Bernstein,  Leonard",
      "workTitle": "WEST SIDE STORY (WITH FILM)",
      "conductorName": "Newman, David",
      "soloists": []
    }
  ]
}]}

So, check the file content you uploaded in storage account.
Also, you check the errors and warnings you are getting when indexer is created.

If you don't find any errors and warnings still facing same issue, possibly you are not referring the documents correctly in storage account and follow below steps to create the data source properly.
Upload this file inside the folder jsonsin your storage account.

Next, create data source with below definition.
{
  "name": "ny-philharmonic-ds2",
  "description": null,
  "type": "azureblob",
  "subtype": null,
  "credentials": {
    "connectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https......."
  },
  "container": {
    "name": "data",
    "query": "jsons"
  },
  "dataChangeDetectionPolicy": null,
  "dataDeletionDetectionPolicy": null
}

Next, reset and run the indexer with this data source.
